# go concurrency architecture surrounding multi step process

Tags: go, concurrency, pipeline, goroutine, channel

I need to create a system that consumes a message from gcp pub/sub which kicks off the following steps:

1. POST client api to create (synchronous)
2. POST client api to register (Async) - requires polling until status changes
3. POST client api to create another entity (leveraging id returned from step 2)
4. POST client api to register (Async) - requires polling until status changes

I was thinking about setting up a job queue with multiple workers - and pass the results from each step into a results channel. My question is best practices surrounding the polling piece.

Comment: If those steps have to be executed in order, that's the opposite of concurrency, so it's unclear what you're asking - what is the problem/question?

Comment: For step 2 to occur, step one has to be successful. Step 2 as well as 4 require polling on the status of a Brand.

Comment: According to your description, step 3 also needs an output from step 2. So it sounds like, at most, steps 3 and 4 might be able to run concurrently?